# Get Data from SQLite into ArrayAdapter / ListView - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to get the data from my SQLite table into a `List<string>` and then into an `ArrayAdapter<string>` and into a `ListView`. 
How would I get the data pulled from the below code, into a `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter`?

DB Helper.cs:

```
  public List<string> getNoteList()
    {
        List<string> noteList = new List<string>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.ReadableDatabase;
        ICursor cursor = db.Query(DB_TABLE, new string[] { DB_COLUMN}, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.MoveToNext())
        {
            int index = cursor.GetColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN);
            noteList.Add(cursor.GetString(index));
        }
        return noteList;
    }
```

As you can see it is put into `noteList`, but how would I code an array adapter so that the `noteList` goes into a `ListView`?

**UPDATE 1:** MainActivity.cs

```
public void LoadNoteList()
        {
            List<string> noteList = dbHelper.getNoteList();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.list_black_text, noteList);
            lvNotes.Adapter = adapter;
        }
```

**Error:**

[image: Error Image]

Comment: do not use `ArrayAdapter`, use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead when your data is `Cursor` based

Comment: How exactly would i add a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: by calling `ListView#setAdapter`

Comment: Yes but what would be the line of code to declare the `SimpleCursorAdapter?`

Comment: See **UPDATE 1**

Comment: you are using custom Resource layout, Resource.Layout.list_black_text   and we are providing you  android default layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1. Problem is here.

Comment: so whats unclear in [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.SimpleCursorAdapter/) ?

Comment: It is ok, your solution let to the answer! thank you!

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Change noteList's type to ArrayList and add follow line at the place after your ListView being initialization

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noteList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How would I change `noteList` to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: See **Update 1**

Answer (score 0):

> try this 
>   here `cards` is my `linked-list`

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        for (MerchantCard card : cards) {
            arrayAdapter.add(card.getName());
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedCardTypeId = cards.get(position).getId();
                Log.d("request", cards.get(position).getId() + " " + cards.get(position).getName());
            }
        });
```

Comment: See **UPDATE 1**